# Plone site files owner

Tags: plone, rsync, file-ownership

I accidentally changed owner of all files on my plone site to plone, and I don't know how to fix this without reinstalling site, which won't be acceptable.

I have backup version which keeps default owners but it's changed in the meanwhile on the dafault site. Maybe rsync can sync only ownerships between these copies???

Any idea would be precious.
Cheers

Comment: Not programming-related - belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Yeah, I would rephrase this as a general filesystem permission question; it's not related to Plone specifically.

Answer (score 2):

```
chown -R user:group /path/to/Ploneroot
```